# Sorting and printing only certain objects in an array with multiple class types, java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, oop

My apologies for being horrible with the terminology...

My program's parent class is Vehicle. Vehicle contains **4 variables**, `make` `model` `date` and `serial`. That class has **two children**, `Car` and `Boat`. `Car` has children `Truck` and `Van`, `Boat` has children `Powerboat` and `Sailboat`. Each of the children has its own specific set of variables. I have an array of type `Vehicle` which contains objects of type `Truck`, `Van`, `Sailboat` and `Powerboat`.

My problem comes when I want to print only `Boat` objects. They need to be sorted by `boatLength`. I get error

> cannot find symbol

in my sorting algorithm:

```
  //regulates the first value
  for (int i = 0; i < input.length-1; i++)
  {
     int min = i;


     //checks remaining values for min
     for (int j = i+1; j < input.length; j++)
     {
        if (input[j].getBoatLength().compareToIgnoreCase(input[min].getBoatLength())<0)
        {
            min = j;
        }  
     }

     //swaps values
     Vehicle temp = input[i];
     input[i] = input[min];
     input[min] = temp;
  }
```

Is there a way I can sort and print only the boat objects without creating an array for the Boat objects?

here is the error message:

```
VehicleClient.java:276: error: cannot find symbol
            if (vehicles[i] instanceof Boat)
                ^
  symbol:   variable vehicles
  location: class VehicleClient
VehicleClient.java:310: error: cannot find symbol
            if (input[j].getBoatLength().compareToIgnoreCase(input[min].getBoatLength())<0)
                        ^
  symbol:   method getBoatLength()
  location: class Vehicle
VehicleClient.java:310: error: cannot find symbol
            if (input[j].getBoatLength().compareToIgnoreCase(input[min].getBoatLength())<0)
                                                                       ^
  symbol:   method getBoatLength()
  location: class Vehicle
3 errors
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Comment: show us the error message,the line where those errors occurs and possible location of yor all class

Comment: @ShadabFaiz "_possible location of yor all class_" What?

Comment: how are you sure input array only contains Boat objects? perhaps calling if(input[i] instanceof Boat) to make sure you are only looking at boats?

Comment: are they in same package or different package.If there are in different package,check if you are able to access them.

Comment: have you defined variable vehicle[] anywhere?

Comment: Sorry Shadab Faiz, either my knowledge is so limited I don't know what your talking about or... nothing you've said is relevant.

Comment: Raz_Muh_Taz, the input array contains all vehicle objects, but not all are boats. there are trucks, vans, sailboats and powerboats. I will try your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is caused by you trying to call a method that is defined in Boat on a reference of type Vehicle. The compiler is searching for `getBoatLength` in the Vehicle class and can't find it (as it is not there). You can solve it by **casting** the variable reference into a `Boat` type reference (if you are sure the object is of type `Boat`).

There are several approaches you can take to tackle what you are asking for. Here are my thoughts:

1. I don't know how you created the array `input`, but I assume you can create two separate arrays instead of one - one for Boat objects and one for Car objects. Then you can use only the Boat array.
2. I'm guessing you need the array as it is, with Car and Boat object together - so the previous approach isn't relevant. As you mentioned - you could create an additional array from the first one for the Boat objects and use the new array. For that you can just create it when you create the original array and add every Boat object to both arrays, or alternatively go over the `input` array and use the very un-oop method `instanceof`:

   ```
   List<Boat> boats = new ArrayList();
   for (Vehicle object : input){
       if (object instanceof Boat){
           boats.add((Boat)object);
       }
   }
   return boats.toArray();
   ```
3. You could also use the `instanceof` to just sort the Boat object in-place in the array you already have and print them:

   ```
   //regulates the first value
   for (int i = 0; i < input.length-1; i++)
   {
       int min = i;   

       //checks remaining values for min
       for (int j = i+1; j < input.length; j++)
       {
           if (!(input[j] instance Boat)){ //check to use only Boat objects
               continue;
           } //now that you are sure it's a Boat object - cast the reference to use it as a Boat object reference
           if (((Boat)input[j]).getBoatLength().compareToIgnoreCase(((Boat)input[min]).getBoatLength())<0)
           {
               min = j;
           }  
       }
       //swaps values
       Vehicle temp = input[i];
       input[i] = input[min];
       input[min] = temp;
   }
   ```

The last approach (approach 3) is probably what you are after, but note that the fact that you need to use the `instanceof` method normally tells you that your design is not really oop. Although you are using polymorphism to call the `boatLength` on objects of different subclasses of Boat, the fact that you need to check which subclass of `Vehicle` is each object in run-time (going over the `input` array) means you are going un-polymorphic there and therefore un-oop-ic. That's why I included approach 1 as well, which is the correct one in my opinion. If you need the Boats as Boats - keep them separated and when you need all the objects refer to the two arrays (the `Car` objects one and the `Boat` objects one) one after the other. You could even have them in another array (currently of size 2) of `Vehicle` arrays, and have a constant that "remembers" which position is the `Boat` objects array:

```
public static final int BOATS_ARR_INDEX = 0;
public static final int CARS_ARR_INDEX = 1;

Vehicle[][] vehicleArrs = new Vehicle[2][];
vehicleArrs[BOATS_ARR_INDEX] = boatsArrayGeneratingMethod();
vehicleArrs[CARS_ARR_INDEX] = carsArrayGeneratingMethod();

for (Vehicle[] vehicleArr : vehicleArrs){
    // do whatever you want to do for all Vehicle objects here, iterating through vehicleArr
}

Boat[] boats = vehicleArrs[BOATS_ARR_INDEX];
//do you original code from the question here
```

Comment: This is for a class and we're only allowed 1 array, which I think is stupid. Your answer should help though, thank you. Prof hasn't responded to either of my emails for help... and this was the last thing I needed to figure out.

Comment: I got it to work, I had to cast both input[min] and input[j], as well as make sure that input[min] was an instanceof Boat.